# GoogleCloudMessaging cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, google-api

I am the only person that is experiencing this problem in the world. So I really need an expert, I think.

- I am using Eclipse with Android Development Tools.
- I have added ALL of the relevant libraries to the project
- I have added gcm.jar

GoogleCloudMessaging cannot be resolved to a type

[image]

How can I resolve this problem? I cannot see any people that have the same problem.

Here are my library includes

[image]

I even tried changing Project Build Target, which does not help at all.

[image]

Then I finally tried the Java Build Target one. Which does not help too.

[image]

So I'm stuck here. I want only to use the GoogleCloudMessaging class. But I can't.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Uh, try hitting `ctrl-shift-o`

Comment: Hitting ctrl-shift-o did not help me, tried a couple of times. It cannot find GoogleCloudMessaging class in any library.

Comment: it looks like, you only need to import it in the import section of your java file. eclipse can do that for you, if you try to autocomplete GoogleCloudMessaging

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The GoogleCloudMessaging class is in com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging, which is part of the [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html).

You'll need to [download](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) the Play Services through the SDK manager and then add that to your project as well.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you so much.

It's also interesting that there is no documentation about that.

Answer (score 7):

Thats right -- you need to add google-play-services-lib jar file from "your sdk folder/extras/google/google-play-services/libproject " some thing like that add this jar file and import the librariy after that ( CTRL + SHIFT + o ) and you will see it will fix

Answer (score 5):

`gcm-server.jar` is for the third party server. But to implment the GoogleCloudMessaging in your android app you need to include `google-play-services.jar` file

check [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) to know how to setup google play service

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `google-play-services_lib` to your project.

Answer (score 2):

Just add '**google-play-services.jar**' to ur project. This jar is available at location ur- android-sdk-folder/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs/

> but before this you need to install **google play services**

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to at least have JDK 1.7 to use Google Cloud Messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Add Jars from the following directories to your project:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\gcm\gcm-server\lib*.jar

There is also a client Jar for gcm but I didnot need to include this one
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\gcm\gcm-client\lib\android.jar

If you don't have the above folders then Open Android SDK Manager and click on Obsolete packages. Then select GCM package from extras list

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio / Gradle you need to add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

(the version number might change) to your build.gradle file in the app module. The SDK is now part of Google Play

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Android Studio, make sure that in your build.gradle you have:

```
dependencies {compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'

}
```